# Writing files within native code in Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface, native-code

This seems like a trivial question, so whoever can answer first and provide me with a resource, I'd be happy to provide you with a green tick :)

How can I write files from within native code? I want to perform some processing in C++ which will output a .txt file, so I'd like to save that to the SD card. (I tried and it told me permission denied).

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to add this to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in default, android denies you of writing to external storage unless you specify your desire to..

Comment: Ah, see, I never tried to write from within Android (only within native code) so I didn't realize this was an android-wide issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Brian D - the reason is, even though you're writing native code, it still runs in the Android sandbox so you are still subject to the normal Android security model.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks